# Designing SQL database in visio

Tags: sql-server, visio, er-diagram

I want to design a schema of my SQL database in Visio

But the default database is Microsoft Access, and some datatypes do not exist there (such as tinyint).

How can i change the database type to SQL ? I'm using visio 2007

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

To change the target database driver.

- On the Database menu, point to Options, and then click Drivers.
- On the Drivers tab, select the Visio driver for your target database management system.
- Click Setup and select the check box for the appropriate ODBC driver.

Changing to something like SQL server (if you have it installed) should give you the option to use tinyint

Source [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HA101154811033.aspx#3)

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be looking for the same thing in Visio 2010 it's now moved to Database menu > Database drivers > Drivers tab